# echo image from converting text-to-image

Tags: php, image, text

I found this code for converting text-to-image and I wanted to echo the result

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

for example I saved that code to image.php, I can echo that image by

```
echo"<img src='image.php'>";
```

but I don't want to do that way, because if I did, I cant assign variable text.

Is there any other way to print the image from that code?

Comment: What do you mean with "I cant assign variable text."? You can always use $_GET-Parameters in the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your image.php

replace

```
 $text = 'Testing...';
```

with

```
 $text=$_GET["text"];
```

and your code to print

```
echo"<img src='image.php?text=AnotherText...'>";
```

Hope this is what you want?

EDIT:

```
<form action="image.php" method="post">
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in your image.php file instead of

```
$text=$_GET["text"];
```

use

```
$text=$_POST["text"];
```

Comment: I have a long text to pass. Like a 600 word article type. Is it ok to pass that way?

Comment: why would you convert an article to an image for a web site?

Comment: It is OK to pass long GET variables. Though maybe you could consider storing all the text in a database then calling image.php?id=1 (where the ID then hits a lookup table through mySQL to get the text).

Comment: For headers that use special fonts.

Comment: @IvorySantos, If this solution helped you please mark this solution as accepted so that people will know that your problem has been solved.