# echo image from converting text-to-image is it possible to only apply this code to bold text

Tags: php, css, image, text

I found this code for converting text-to-image and I wanted to echo the result here:
[echo image from converting text-to-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896327/echo-image-from-converting-text-to-image?rq=1)

But I would like to apply it to only words that I have chosen to be bold so that when ever I make a piece of text bold the php script will output a image version of the text that has bold tags (the output image doesnot have to be bold tho)

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Any help in using this script to only select bold text would be awesome thank you

Comment: Just replace $font = 'arial.ttf'; with the bold font you want to use.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this rather than use a custom font-face via CSS?  This a fairly expensive process and I recommend not this unless it's absolutely necessary.